# Prim's Algorithem, please explain

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, boolean, prims-algorithm

can some one explain to me what is currently happening in this loop?
This is a part of a code for my assignment on Prim's algorithm.

I get the: while countIcluded is not vertices.length, part.
I need to understand what's happening below. 
it's worth to mention that `included` is an array of booleans.

Expect that I'm new to this, because I am and please explain as simple as possible (if possible) so I can understand the basics.

```java
while (countIncluded != vertices.length) {

    // find the not included vertex with minimum cost
    int u = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        if (!included[i]) {
            if (u == -1 || C[u] > C[i])
                u = i;
        }
    }

    // include in MST
    included[u] = true;
    countIncluded++;
}
```

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535655/prims-algorithem-please-explain) and add loop end (`}`)

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? The for-loop? The if-conditions? It's basically "loop over all vertices and if the vertex at index i is not included and get the first vertex (u == -1) or the one with the greates C (C[u] > C[i]) - then mark the vertex at index u as included".

Comment: Why do you not ask whoever gave you the assignment?

Comment: It may help to show what `C[]` is declared as in the question so people don't have to guess. I'm not practiced with this algorithm though so it may be obvious.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/dsa/prim-algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the comments make it cleared:

```
      while (countIncluded != vertices.length) { 

            //u represents a previous i value 
            int u = -1; //value serves as flag for "first time use"  

            //the purpose of this loop is to iterate over included array, which presumably 
            //if of the same length as vertices.
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) { 
                if (!included[i]) { //execute if the value of included[i] is false
                    /* execute if one of these apply:
                       u value is -1 : meaning that it is the first time 
                       included[i] is false (and there is not previous value to compare to).
                       OR C[u] > C[i] : previous vertex value  > current vertex value
                     */
                    if (u == -1 || C[u] > C[i])    
                                      u = i;     //keep i value, the index of the lowest vertex
                                                 //value so far 
                }
            }

            //at the end of the for loop u is the index of the lowest C[u]
            included[u] = true;
            countIncluded++;
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

So basically what this algorithm is doing is going through a list of vertices, and creating a path based on the cost from one vertex to another. Cost is simply just a term to explain the difficulty getting from one vertex to another, commonly just being distance. Let's get into the code.

```java
while (countIncluded != vertices.length) {
```

I know you said you understood what this means, but I'll still go over it. This while loop will make sure you run through every vertex in the array, so that every one is connected to at least one other.

```java
int u = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
```

I combined these two lines, because the first one doesn't do much. The variable `u` is the index of the current vertex in question. It is initially set to -1, because that is not a valid position in an array. The next line, the `for` loop, is just looping over every vertex in the given array.

```java
if (!included[i]) {
    if (u == -1 || C[u] > C[i])
        u = i;
```

The first line simply checks to see if the current value of `i`, or the current vertex is already included in the tree. If it is, we don't need to check again, and continue with the next one. The next line first checks to see if `u` is equal to -1. As stated above, -1 is just a temporary placeholder value, and this check makes sure that it will always point to a valid vertex. The second check is checking if the cost of `u` is greater than the cost of `i`. This is what is actually doing the algorithm. What it is basically doing is getting the cost of `u`, or the temporary vertex. It is then checking that against the cost of `i`. If the cost of `i` is less than the cost of `u`, then set `u` to `i`. In doing this, it will find the vertex with the lowest cost, because it remembers the value of `u` throughout the entire thing.

```java
included[u] = true;
countIncluded++;
```

The first line sets the index of `u` in your array to true. This will make sure that it won't be checked again in your algorithm, to prevent an endless loop of checking the same vertex every single iteration. After that, `countIncluded` is incremented to keep track of the number of vertices currently added.

I hope this helps! Don't hesitate to ask for me to clarify anything!

Comment: Amazing :) 
Thank you! Helped a lot.